# How to search using jpa specifications on a join of 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, join, specifications

I have 2 tables, namely, table1 and table2.
I want to have a JPA specification that searches on the join of the two tables, i.e., some fields on table1 and some fields of table2.
The 2 tables look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Table1 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SID1", nullable = false)
    private Long sid1;

    @Column(name = "field1")
    private Long field1;

    @Column(name = "field2")
    private String field2;

    @Column(name = "SID2", nullable = false)
    private Long sid2;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SID2")
    private Table2 t2;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
public class Table2 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SID2", nullable = false)
    private Long sid2;

    @Column(name = "field01")
    private Long field01;

    @Column(name = "field02")
    private String field02;
}
```

I want to build a Specification and its SpecificationBuilde but have no idea how to refer to the fields of table 2 from root.get(). For ex

```
public static Specification<Table1> hasField01(final String field) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("t2.field01"), field); //is this correct??
    }
```

I explored the idea of making 2 queries to each table separately but that becomes cumbersome.
Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to do a FULL OUTER JOIN? Otherwise the tables should be linked by a foreign key and you need to join on the key. For example if Table1 is Bookshelf and Table2 is Book, then either Bookshelf should have a List<Book> or Book should have a BookshelfId as a foreign key. Which one would you want to implement?

Comment: Can you post the SQL you are trying to generate, then we could translate it into JPQL.

Comment: Hi @roccobaroccoSC I have edited the question to be more direct.
Let me know if any explanation is needed.

Comment: Criteria api is just like JPQL, but each '.' is a separate get call. So instead of root.get("t2.field01"), assuming root is on table1, it would be root.get("t2").get("field01") to give you a Path to use in other expressions such as equal.

Comment: Thanks, this might just work. Will implement today and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to search on Table2.field01 when joined to Table1, you can use the following JPQL query:

```
SELECT 
    t1
FROM 
    Table1 t1 
    LEFT JOIN t1.t2 t2
WHERE 
    t2.field01 = :field
```

This will select Table1 but only the records that joined with Table2 have the field01 equal to the specified parameter. ":field" must be provided as an argument to the query from the outside like so:

```
public class Table1DAO {
    // ...
    public List<Table1> findByField01(Long field01)
    {
        try {
            List<Table1> result = entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT t1 FROM  Table1 t1  LEFT JOIN t1.t2 t2 WHERE t2.field01 = :field", Table1.class)
                .setParameter("field", field01)
                .getResultList();

            return result;
        }
        catch (NoResultException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

You could select all fields from both tables or an arbitrary combination of fields, but your query cannot convert such results to Table1, you need to read them raw from the returned array:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> results = (List<Map<String, Object>>) query.getResultList();
```

Comment: for some reasons i just cannot use JPQL, i have to use specification instead. this is because a lot of fields are there and any number of those can have a value or not. and while some of those values are in table1 and others in table2, hence the question.

Comment: By specifications do you mean JPA's criteria api?